# CASE STATEMENT TO WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: t-sql, case

I have a case statement,and i want to write seperate where clauses for each of them HIGH LOW MEDIUM and NONE.

```
 CASE
                 WHEN (ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(ldd.Value, '%', '')) = 0) 
                                  THEN 'NONE'                    
                 WHEN (CONVERT(FLOAT,REPLACE(ldd.Value, '%', '')) > 9.0)
                                   THEN 'HIGH'                   
                 WHEN (CONVERT(FLOAT,REPLACE(ldd.Value, '%', '')) < 7.0 )
                                    THEN 'LOW'      
                 WHEN (CONVERT(FLOAT,REPLACE(ldd.Value, '%','')) BETWEEN 7.0 AND 9.0  )
                                   THEN 'MEDIUM'                    
                 WHEN (ISNULL(ldd.Value,'') = '')      
                                THEN 'NONE'    
                 END
```

when i try writing the where clause for NONE

```
    SELECT class
           ,rollno
           ,Value
    FROM STUDENT
    WHERE (ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(ldd.Value, '%', '')) = 0)
```

Error MSg:The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

When i write for the high

```
 SELECT class
               ,rollno
               ,Value
        FROM STUDENT
        WHERE (CONVERT(FLOAT,REPLACE(ldd.Value, '%', '')) > 9.0)
```

Error MSg:Error converting data type varchar to float.

what can be done to get only the records for high low or none while writng for where clause?
THE VALUE FIELD IS VARCHAR

Comment: Your first problem is you are evaluating a `VARCHAR` column against numbers. Your errors are coming from the data, not the query. On top of that `ISNUMERIC` will return 1 for more than 0-9; there are a whole slew of things that SQL Server thinks are numeric including commas and dates.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/IsNumeric/71512/

Answer (score 2):

The order of evaluation for the CASE statement prevents you from ever calling CONVERT() on a varchar that can't be converted.  You are not guaranteed to have this protection with a WHERE condition.

Comment: It's not just that, his WHERE condition includes ISNUMERIC which in no way guarantees that only values containing numbers will be filtered out. `SELECT ISNUMERIC('.')` returns 1, as does `SELECT ISNUMERIC('$12')` and `SELECT ISNUMERIC(',')`.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend *entirely* on what is in the Value column. I am assuming they are something similar to AYP or other standardized testing where values are typically reported as xx.x%. In that case, something like this would work:

```
SELECT
    s.Value
    ,CASE WHEN REPLACE(s.Value, '%', '') BETWEEN '0.1' AND '7.0' THEN 'LOW'   
          WHEN REPLACE(s.Value, '%','') BETWEEN '7.0' AND '9.0' THEN 'MEDIUM'  
          WHEN REPLACE(s.Value, '%', '') BETWEEN '9.0' AND '100.0' THEN 'HIGH'   
     ELSE 'NONE'
     END
FROM Student AS s
```